# Failover to 3G and back

Tags: c#, lan, 3g, failover, network-interface

I'm developing an app for remote monitoring of a small power plant. The idea is to keep the remote connection all the time.

We hava a small PC with broadband connection and in addition 3G/4G modem attached.

Checking the connectivity when I have broadband is quite easy for me.

fist I check if the interface that Im using is up,  and then just with simple web client i check the response from google or any other site that I assume that should be online :-)

Im using `System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.*`

Then if there is no connection over the lan network Im connecting to 3G modem and starting 3G connection.

The problem is how to check if my lan connection again got the internet connection and disconnect 3G modem? How to check that particular interface from C# code that it has internet access?

Can I make some manual routing trough the interfaces, or its done somewhere inside the OS it self?

Some advice? Someone has got similar project?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could fetch the Lan connection profile with the same library as the Profile Name is "Ethernet" and then to check you'll first need to connect to a LAN connection and then check and if the connection has internet access the stay else you'll have to switch back. I tried it it takes roughly 30 seconds to do a full route